# I can not change the object in Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have   `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Меню");
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

when creating activity I install `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` after some of the actions that I do in the fragment I need to install `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`. but I can not refer to it from a fragment.

```
public class AuthDialog extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           if (response){
               //then I need to set mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            }else{
               ...
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like ridsatrio said. And then you call the method like this from your `Fragment`:

```
if(getActivity() != null){
    ((YourActivityName)getActivity()).enableDrawerToggle();
}
```

Comment: Silly me, yes I should've mentioned the way to call it. By the way, be careful when using `getActivity()` as it would sometimes return `null`.

Comment: Yes, it is true. Check for null to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make a public method in your `Activity` to enable the `DrawerToggle`. Something that would look like this:

```
public void enableDrawerToggle() {
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
}
```

..and then call it from your `Fragment`.

Comment: I tried to do so, but the method is not evident from the fragment. and if you make it a static mistake. my Activitн MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: What do you mean by "not evident"? If the method is set to `public` it should be accessible from literally everywhere.

Comment: but is not accessible. and it public